# Calendar-App shows events incorrectly (with googlecalendar)

Tags: applications

The elementaryOS calendar-app is quite nice but does mix my events up. They are not displayed on the correct dates like they are listet in the googlecalendar-webpage.

Does anybody encounter the same issue?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what Calendar lists vs. what Google Calendar lists? Thanks!

Comment: Screenshot: https://picload.org/image/rdoadlri/calendar-bug.png
Have a look at Event C. I created it in the calendar-app for 14. oct but it appears on 13. oct. On the left is googlecalendar-website, which shows it correctly.
Besides the displaying-mismatch, the calendar-app does not refresh the Events I created before on the googlecalendar-website (Event A + Event B).

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue.  I have reported it as bug in Launchpad:

[Calendar bugs page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/maya/+bug/1632014)

You can mark that it affect to you, to bring devs attention to it.